# Are active and passive parity transformation different?

Tags: coordinate-systems, conventions, parity

As per [this Phys.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/460996/) post, an active parity transformation is when a particle at $(a,b,c)$ is reflected about origin to move it to $(-a,-b,-c)$. A passive one is when the particle is still at the exact point in space but its position is now described by $(−a,−b,−c)$.

How can these be one and the same (if they are) since in the latter case, the coordinate system has become left-handed and in the former the system is right-handed since no change has been made to it?

Answer (score 1):

We can freely choose to assign coördinates using left-handed axes or right-handed axes, so the handedness of the coördinate system by itself is a notational convention, not a property of the physical object (conversely, the handedness of the physical object makes no sense unless we have something to compare against). However, the handedness of the object *relative* to the coördinate system is a measurable property of the object.

If we start with an object that appears right-handed in a right-handed coördinate system, we can active transform which results in an object which appears left-handed in a right-handed coördinate system, or we can passive transform which results in an object which appears right-handed in a left-handed coördinate system. In either case, the relative handedness is opposite, so the two transformed objects are distinguishable from the initial state, but indistinguishable from each other.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by 'handed-ness of the object'?

Comment: The handedness of an object would be its projection onto the axes. If it matches the axes, it would be right-handed, if it doesn't it's left-handed. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/3D_Cartesian_Coodinate_Handedness.jpg

Comment: Of course we usually call a left hand a left-handed object even in a left-handed coördinate system, but this is just because we implicitly compare everything in right-handed coördinates. You could call it "same as coördinate" vs. "opposite from coördinate" instead if that makes more sense to you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm still not able to comprehend what do you mean by 'handedness is projection into the axes, if it matches...... '. Could you give any general example?